# sending response back to the client from Server

Tags: java, spring-integration, tcpclient, tcpsocket

Following is my Server code where I am creating one thread for reading data from socket and another thread for sending data, it's receiving data correctly and also data is sent back **but the data is not received to client, My client program is System which is designed using Spring Integration, it's using TcpSendingMessageHandler and TcpReceivingChannelAdapter** for sending and receiving data.

What may be the possible reasons ? What changes do i need to do in Server ?

```
    public class Server
{
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName());  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FileHandler fileHandler = null;
        int port = 3000;        

        try{                
            fileHandler = new FileHandler("/home/client/ServerLog.txt");
            //fileHandler = new FileHandler("d:/ServerLog.txt");
            LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler);        
            LOGGER.info("Server Started");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);                          
            LOGGER.info("Waiting for Connection...!");          

            while(true)
            {
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();              
                System.out.println("Connected to : "+server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                ReadThread hldcon = new ReadThread(server);                                     
                Thread t1 = new Thread(hldcon);             
                t1.start();                         
            }

        }catch(SocketException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          try {
                System.out.println("Server Exception...!");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e1) 
              {             
                e1.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }         
}

public class ReadThread implements Runnable
{
      boolean runflag = true;
      Socket server;
      private byte[] bytarrHeader = null;
      private byte[] bytarrMsg = null;
      FileHandler fileHandler = null;
      int msgheaderlength = 2;  

      private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName());

    public ReadThread(Socket serverSocket) 
    {   
        this.server = serverSocket;
    }

    public void setArrymsg(byte[] bytarrMsg)
    {
        this.bytarrMsg = bytarrMsg;
    }

    public byte[] getArrymsg()
    {
        return this.bytarrMsg;
    }   
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
          byte[] bytarrHeader = null;
          byte[] bytarrMsg = null;
          bytarrHeader = new byte[msgheaderlength];
          InputStream in = null;
          byte response [] = null;                    

        try{

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(runflag)
        {  
        try{                    
                in = server.getInputStream();
                int nRead = in.read(bytarrHeader);

                if(nRead != -1)
                {
                    System.out.println("number bytes returned : "+nRead);

                      //  reading data and setting in byte format using setArrayMsg method  

                        setArrymsg(bytarrMsg);

                        WriteThread wrt = new WriteThread(server,this);    // Starting write thread
                        Thread t2 = new Thread(wrt);
                        t2.start();                         
                        Thread.sleep(2000);                                                     
                }                   

        }catch(SocketException e)
        {             
                    System.out.println("Error...!");
                    runflag = false;                        
                    try {
                        server.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {                      
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runflag = false;
        }

      }
    }
}

public class WriteThread  implements  Runnable
{    
     Socket server;
     ReadThread rd; 

     //responseData = new ResponseData();           
    public WriteThread(Socket server,ReadThread rd) 
    {
        super();
        this.server = server;
        this.rd = rd;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() 
    {       
        try{                
            byte[] bytarrMsg = rd.getArrymsg(); 

            OutputStream out = server.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytarrMsg);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Your `setArrymsg` doesn't appear to do anything - it just replaces the field with itself (which is null). Perhaps you have more code that you haven't shown. You also need to show your client configuration. Also, your code is a bit strange (and inefficient), starting a new write thread for each read.

Comment: I am receiving data on server side frequently so I don't want to block the server port if I reading one of received data. I was thinking that I should get the data and give it to one thread so that server is ready to take next data.

Comment: Well, then you'll have problems with interleaved replies - you really can't have two threads writing to the same socket at the same time. Why don't you use Spring Integration on the server side too? It will take care of all those low-level details for you.

Comment: My main System is client so i am just  using this server as simulator, wiil change it ..! thanks for reply